# OptionsMenu Item Styling

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-optionsmenu

I'm using ActionBar Sherlock and Action Bar Style Generator for styles. That's what I have:

[image: View Image]

Now I need to change the color of the item text to white and reduce the space between the text (Barcelona) and the icon, but I don't find the propoerties I need to modify (the background of the png image is not the problem).

My styles XML:

```
 Copyright (C) 2011 The Android Open Source Project
 Copyright (C) 2012 readyState Software Ltd

 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.-->
<resources>

<style name="Theme.Example" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Example</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Example</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Example</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_example</item>
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_example</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Example</item>
    <item name="itemTextAppearance">@style/myCustomMenuTextApearance</item>

</style>

<style name="myCustomMenuTextApearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.IconMenu.Item">
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_example</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_example</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_example</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Example</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_example</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Example</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ListPopupWindow">  
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example</item>   
</style>

<style name="DropDownListView.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_example</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownNav.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_example</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBar.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_example</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_example</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>

<!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
<style name="Theme.Example.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Example</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this I hope it'll help you, because it helps me..:)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
<style name="YOURTHEME" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/YOURTHEME.ActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/YOURTHEME.ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

 <style name="YOURTHEME.ActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/YOURTHEME.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/YOURTHEME.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="YOURTHEME.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/YOUR_COLOR</item>
    <item name="textColor">@color/YOUR_COLOR</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimension/MEDIUM_TEXT</item>
    <item name="textSize">@dimension/MEDIUM_TEXT</item>
</style>
</resources>
```